# Is there a way to do a offline directory changes through ldif file?

Tags: ldif, opendj

I have a ldif file containing multiple modify operations. I would like to apply them offline, as ldif-import can import data in a off-line manner.

I've looked at ldif-import, but I understand it can only apply add operations, not modify operation. I tried with this tool, but every operation was rejected.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The import-ldif tool is meant to do fast import of data to the OpenDJ directory server, not to do offline processing.

OpenDJ has a tool called ldifmodify which allows to apply one or more operations (expressed in LDIF representation) against an existing LDIF file (representing the entries).

Please read the documentation of OpenDJ for the details and examples.

Regards,

Ludovic.